# Как изменить знаки элементов предыдущей строки в матрице на противоположные при определённом условии?

Tags: python

Проверить, есть ли в матрице хотя бы одна строка, содержащая элемент, равный нулю, и найти её номер. Знаки элементов предыдущей строки изменить на противоположные.

Я только знаю, как сделать первую часть. Как изменить знаки элементов предыдущей строки на противоположные?

Например: строка `[7, 2, 0]` содержит хотя бы один нулевой элемент, тогда в строке `[-5, -6, 2]` необходимо изменить знаки.

Пожалуйста, как можно сделать?

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 0], [8, 4, -9]]

row = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] == 0:
            row = i
            print("The row", row," has at least one zero element.")
```

Comment: Пройтись по строке и умножить элементы на -1

Comment: а что делать, если первая строка содержит 0?

Comment: Это я не знаю, как это сделать, если первая строка содержит 0

Comment: у первой строки нет предыдущей строки. Что по вашему надо сделать с тем чего нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбиваем задачу на подзадачи: сначала находим индекс строки хотя бы с одним элементом, равным нулю, потом меняем знак элементов предыдущей строки.

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 0], [8, 4, -9]]

def get_zero_line(m):
     for i, line in enumerate(m):
         if any(x == 0 for x in line):
             return i
     return None  # Ни в одной строке нет нулевого элемента

i = get_zero_line(matrix)
if i is not None and i > 0:
    prev_line = matrix[i-1]
    for j, _ in enumerate(prev_line):
        prev_line[j] *= -1
```

Обратите внимание, как можно использовать `enumerate(x)` вместо `range(len(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 0], [8, 4, -9]]

prev_arr = None

for curr_arr in matrix:
    for elem in curr_arr:
        if elem == 0:
            if prev_arr:
                for i in range(len(prev_arr)):
                    prev_arr[i] *= -1
            break
    prev_arr = curr_arr

print str(matrix) # выведет [[5, 6, -2], [7, 2, 0], [8, 4, -9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 0], [8, 4, -9]]

matrix_result = [matrix[0]] + [list(map(lambda x: x * ((-1) ** int(0 in matrix[i - 1])), matrix[i])) 
    for i in range(1, len(matrix))]

print(matrix_result)

# [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 0], [-8, -4, 9]]
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].